# Objective c -set FBSDKAccessToken with an existing access token string

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

I implemented the Facebook SDK in my app.
The login process works fine. I'm creating in my webserver a long-lived token.
After the process has been finished in my webserver, I'm getting back the extended access token string.

How can I set the global FBSDKAccessToken with the access token string?

I can see that there is a function setCurrentAccessToken but it need to get  FBSDKAccessToken object.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the access token is given to you and it is changing every 30 mins or so. Thus, the user must log in to get the access token.

Comment: I'm doing this process after the user has already logged in to my app. I'm sending to my webservice the short term access token and receiving back an extended access token.

Comment: I need the next requests to facebook to be with the extended token to get long term Page access token.

Comment: I don't think you can set the temp/changing access token with your own.
If I understand you, you need to create a class in your project with 2 access tokens: FB and your server. You can't mix with those two into the FB SDK.

Comment: So how can i send facebook requests with a long-live access token?

Comment: Again, there is no such thing as "long live access token" (unless someone will correct me).
You have a temp access token and with this token you can do whatever you want, until it changes again.
30 mins is a lot of time...